# Output of sliding FFT with a white noise input

Tags: fft

I'm currently in the process of porting a customer's algorithm for Matlab/Simulink to a DSP. In their algorithm, they perform a sliding DFT on a sinusoid and they use bin 1 to estimate the frequency.

Their algorithm looks like this

$y[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}{x[n-N+k+1]e^{\frac{-jk}{N}}}$ where x[n] is the input signal. Then my client computes the phase of y[n].  Usually it is a high-SNR sinusoid, but in some cases there's no signal except the input noise.

If x[n] is a white-noise sequence, is there an expression to describe y[n] and the phase of y[n]?

Comment: $y[n]$ will also be a white noise sequence, since it's a weighted sum of white noise sequences. Compare, e.g., [1] for more information on this.

[1] Richards, Mark A. “The Discrete-Time Fourier Transform and Discrete Fourier Transform of Windowed Stationary White Noise.” Georgia Institute of Technology, Technical Memorandum, November 24, 2013.

Comment: Is it really $y[n]$ and not something like $y[k]$? Your notation is ambiguous otherwise: the index on the left side of the equation conflicts with the summing variable on the right.

Comment: I will correct my question tomorrow

Comment: If I see it correctly, the derivation of the uniformly distributed phase is in the reference above. Are certain steps missing there?